# Drawing Implicit functions in an image (Python,[OpenCV])

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, curve

I need to draw a curved line based on a function in an image. Something like x^2+y^2=1, without converting it to explicit form, because not all functions I use can be converted easily in this way. For regular implicit functions, I use cv2.polylines with the x and y points for drawing the curve in my image, and I would like to know from you guys if there is a similar solution for explicit functions. All I've found so far use matplotlib to plot the graph using plt.contour. But this does not seem really useful to me. Please Help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is matplotlib pyplot not useful?  Seems to be the most direct way. You can also iterate over x and y and compute points from your function, then use cv2.polylines() to draw your result on your image or on a constant background. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga1ea127ffbbb7e0bfc4fd6fd2eb64263c

Comment: I'm creating images in opencv in the rest of the pipeline, and this function would have to be drawn in the same image. So I figured, you couldn't really write the image unless you loop over every pixel

Answer (score 0):

You can render it like this, sorry, I am C++ fan ) hope the idea is clear for python programmers.

```
// Your function 
float func(float x, float y)
{
    // x * x * sin(x) + y * y = 1
    return (x * x * sin(x) + y * y - 1);
}
// render it 
void plotXY()
{
    // canvas size
    int height = 800;
    int width = 800;
    // plot scale
    float scale = 0.1;
    // cavas
    cv::Mat result=cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);
    // move origin to canvas center
    float cx = (float)width / 2.0f;
    float cy = (float)height / 2.0f;
    // precompute scale
    float sx = (scale * (float)width);
    float sy = (scale * (float)height);

    // scan for zero crossings
    for (uint32_t i = 1; i < height-1; ++i)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 1; j < width-1; ++j)
        {
            // transform screen space to real space
            float x =  ((float)j -     cx) / sx;
            float x1 = ((float)(j-1) - cx) / sx;
            float x2 = ((float)(j+1) - cx) / sx;
            float y =  ((float)i -     cy) / sy;
            float y1 = ((float)(i-1) - cy) / sy;
            float y2 = ((float)(i+1) - cy) / sy;
            // if zero crossimg along x put pixel
            if ( func(x1,y)* func(x2, y) < 0)
            {
                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 255);
            }
            // if zero crossimg along y put pixel
            if (func(x, y1) * func(x, y2) < 0)
            {
                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 255);
            }
        }
    }

    // show and save result
    cv::imshow("plot", result);
    cv::imwrite("plot.jpg", result);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

The result for function x * x * sin(x) + y * y = 1 will be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use a similar implementation. It seems I cannot do without the nested for loops. I wanted a faster way, but this solution does the job.